# How can I find close-together points in a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, geocoding

I've got a PostgreSQL table of geographic `nodes`, each of which has a `latitude` and `longitude`. If any two nodes are less than 1 km apart, there's a good chance that one of them was created erroneously.

**How can I detect this?**

### An Extremely Slow Solution

The "brute force" way is basically, "for each node, examine each other node and see how far it is from the first one. If it's less than 1 km, add the pair to a list."

An SQL implementation would be:

```
SELECT
  n1.id AS n1_id, n1.latitude AS n1_lat, n1.longitude AS n1_long,
  n2.id AS n2_id, n2.latitude AS n2_lat, n2.longitude AS n2_long
FROM
  nodes n1
INNER JOIN nodes n2 ON (
  n1.id != n2.id
  AND earth_distance(
    ll_to_earth(n1.latitude, n1.longitude),
    ll_to_earth(n2.latitude, n2.longitude)
  ) < 1000
)
```

This is horribly slow; for N nodes, there are roughly N<sup>2</sup> pairs to examine. On my database, it's infeasible to do this.

Comment: I think that the "brute force" approach is the only 100% correct one, but maybe there's some heuristic that would detect most cases and would be faster?

Comment: Looks like this is a closely-related question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71926/how-to-detect-duplicates-and-keep-only-one

Comment: Maybe create a "distances" table with columns `n1, n2, d`? This allows computation to run in batches.

Comment: if earth_distance(point1, point2) = earth_distance(point2, point1) then you can do small optimization: change `n1.id != n2.id` to `n1.id < n2.id`. This eliminates half of pairs to examine.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you **restrict** your join to only "nearby" nodes?

Create 2 indexes on table `nodes`:

```
CREATE INDEX I_NODES_LAT ON NODES (LATITUDE, ID);
CREATE INDEX I_NODES_LON ON NODES (LONGITUDE, ID);
ANALYZE NODES;
```

Second, try this way:

```
SELECT
  n1.id AS n1_id, n1.latitude AS n1_lat, n1.longitude AS n1_long,
  n2.id AS n2_id, n2.latitude AS n2_lat, n2.longitude AS n2_long
FROM
  nodes n1
INNER JOIN nodes n2 ON  n1.id != n2.id

-- the trick is to get only nearby nodes. 
-- You can mess with "0.1" to restrict even more... It is just as guess...
AND N2.latitude  between (N1.latitude - 0.1)  and (N1.latitude + 0.1)
AND N2.longitude between (N1.longitude - 0.1) and (N1.longitude + 0.1) 

WHERE
  earth_distance
  (
    ll_to_earth(n1.latitude, n1.longitude),
    ll_to_earth(n2.latitude, n2.longitude)
  ) < 1000
```

Comment: Neat idea. http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674/37735 is useful for deciding the difference in degrees to use

Comment: I haven't tried the index yet, but just adding a conservative lat/long math check before the `earth_distance` comparison makes the query much faster. (It's still ~1 hr for my data, but it doesn't need to be realtime; it's just a report.) Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure when you create those indexes, it'll get even better!

Comment: For my purposes, it ended up being good enough to use *only* lat/long math as an approximation of distance. It's less accurate, but *much* faster.

Answer (score 1):

To find all nodes without a nearby other node, use an outer self-join that filters out matches for near nodes found:

```
SELECT n1.*
FROM nodes n1
LEFT JOIN nodes n2 ON n1.id != n2.id
    AND earth_distance(
        ll_to_earth(n1.latitude, n1.longitude),
        ll_to_earth(n2.latitude, n2.longitude)
    ) < 1000
WHERE n2.id IS NULL
```

That should run in an acceptable time. If not, you could optimuze the query considerably by pre-calculating all the `ll_to_earth()` values *once* for each node using a [constant table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude) earth
    FROM nodes
)
SELECT n1.*
FROM cte n1
LEFT JOIN cte n2 ON n1.id != n2.id
    AND earth_distance(n1.earth, n2.earth) < 1000
WHERE n2.id IS NULL
```

That should run quite a bit faster.

Comment: Your query finds the opposite of what I want; I want the nodes *with* another nearby node. But it was a good idea to pre-calculate the `ll_to_earth()` values. I decided to use a temporary table for that instead.